# asterisk wildcard not working

Tags: zip

I am trying to zip all PHP files including those in subfolders. But

```
zip -r PHP.zip *.php
```

only zips php files under current folder, if I do

```
zip -r ALL.zip *
```

it can zip all files including subfolders. So what is wrong with "*.php"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use,

```
find -iname '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 zip -r php.zip
```

or

```
zip -r php.zip . --include \*.php
```

Both of the above commands will do the job.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Could you please tell me where I can find a detailed instruction in regards how to use ZIP command and other command as well?

Comment: Sure. On Linux run `man zip` in terminal to read manual of `zip` command. It has nice description with examples. In manual, search `--include` to see above example. Similarly, for `find` command, run `man find` in terminal and go to `EXAMPLES` section. Hope this helps.